# Transaction History/ Metada of NFT'S on Etherum blockchain

Tags: opensea, meta-data

Currently I am working on project and I want to detect different frauds about NFT's, so I need the transaction history of  NFT's and NFT related events. I want to compare different marketplaces and OpenSea has an API but other marketplaces does not have API's. Do you know other marketplaces with API or do you know how ı can download the transaction history/ metadata about the NFT's from other marketplaces?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a lot of that info on Foundation and NiftyGateway.